# Show that $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ is not the boundary of a $4n+1$ dimensional Manifold using Chern classes

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I'm currently studying with the Book "From Calculus to Cohomology" by Madsen & Tornehave(free PDF [here](https://archive.org/details/MadsenI.H.TornehaveJ.FromCalculusToCohomologyDeRhamCohomologyAndCharacteristicClasses1996/page/n193)). 
Unfortunately I am really struggling to understand the Example 18.14 where Chern classes are used to show that $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ is not the boundary of any $4n+1$ dimensional Manifold $R$.

(Here $\tau_{M}$ denotes the tangent bundle for a given Manifold $M$.)

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with almost every point of the calculation where sums are used, which I will list below:

Let $\partial R$ be the boundary of $R$, then we have, that:
$$ \tau_{\partial R}\oplus \epsilon^1_{\mathbb{R}} = i^{\ast}(\tau_R) $$
where $\epsilon^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ denotes the trivial real line bundle.
(I have no idea how to even approach this, but have the feeling that it's extremely trivial..)

Now, if we assume $\partial R = \mathbb{CP}^{2n}$, and complexify, we get
$$ (\tau_{\mathbb{CP}^{2n}})_{\mathbb{RC}} \oplus \epsilon^1_{\mathbb{C}}
 = i^\ast(\tau_R \otimes \mathbb{C}) $$
(i have no idea how to see this.)

The complexification of a real vector bundle $\eta$ is given by
$$ \eta_{\mathbb{C}} = \eta \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \epsilon^1_{\mathbb{C}},$$
where $\epsilon^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the trivial complex line bundle.

Unfortunately I have almost no experience with tensor products and sums, which leaves me kind of confused here.
The rest of the argument, I also don't understand.. but I hope that if this part becomes clear, I can piece together the rest..

Comment: Prove it has a nonzero  pontryagin number

Comment: @CharlieFrohman I‘m preparing this for a Seminar in which pontryagin Numbers aren‘t defined. For now, i would just like to find out why  $\tau_{\partial R}\oplus \epsilon^1_{\mathbb{C}} = i^\ast( \tau_R)$ holds..

Comment: @astrorain This follows from the intuition from linear algebra that one can decompose a vector space as follows $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$ (where $\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement).  In particular, we look at the tangent bundle $\tau_R$ and restrict it to $\partial R$.  Then, choosing a Euclidean metric on $\tau_R$, we get a unique normal vector field along $R$ spanning $\epsilon^1$, so that we do get such an orthogonal decomposition $\tau_{\partial R} \oplus \epsilon_{\mathbb{R}}^1 \cong i^*(\tau_R)$.

Comment: More succinctly, the normal bundle of $\partial X$ in $X$ is trivial, for any manifold with boundary $X$.

Comment: Thanks so much, after reading your comments, it kind of made sense all of a sudden :)